# LINQ query in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm pretty new to C# and Linq programming world.
I Want to do something similar to this, but SubType is a FK to table Type and I can't do what I've done in this example:

```
public static List<DropdownModel> GetSubTypes(List<string> ListTypes)
    {
        List<DropdownModel> SubTypes = new List<DropdownModel>();
        using (DocumentXtractorEntities DataBase = new DocumentXtractorEntities())
        {
            foreach (string TypeID in ListTypes)
            {
                int TypeIDINT = Int32.Parse(TypeID);
                SubTypes.AddRange((from C in DataBase.SubType.Where(s => s.Active && s.TypeID == TypeIDINT)
                            select new DropdownModel()
                            {
                                ID = C.SubTypeID,
                                Description = C.Name,
                                Selected = false
                            }).ToList());
            }
        }
        return SubTypes;
    }
```

So, the code above kinda filters the subtype text box when I chosen one or more Types.
Now, I need to do the opposite, fill the Type List when subtypes are chosen.

I've tried something but I know that isn't possible the way I'm doing this.
My code for now is this:

```
    public static List<DropdownModel> GetTypesBySubTypes(List<string> ListSubTypes)
    {
        List<DropdownModel> Types = new List<DropdownModel>();
        using (DocumentXtractorEntities DataBase = new DocumentXtractorEntities())
        {
            foreach (string SubTypeID in ListSubTypes)
            {
                int SubTypeIDINT = Int32.Parse(SubTypeID);
                Types.AddRange((from C in DataBase.Type.Where(s => s.Active && s.SubType.Contains(SubTypeIDINT))
                                select new DropdownModel()
                                {
                                    ID = C.TypeID,
                                    Description = C.Name,
                                }).ToList());
            }
        }
        return Types;
    }
```

[EDIT]

I've manage to do a sql query to do the job:

```
select T.TypeID from Type T join SubType ST on St.TypeID=T.TypeID
where ST.SubTypeID=3
```

But I don't know how to transform that to a linq query and do a Type.AddRange().

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Try following : var query = (from t in DataBase.Type
   join on st in DataBase.SubType.Where(x => x.SubTypeID == 3) on t.TypeID equal st.TypeID
   select new { type = t, subtype = st}).ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Intersect` method to find the types that include any subtypes from the list of provided subtypes. This also eliminates the need to iterate using `foreach` and leaving that for Linq to handle.

```
List<int> subTypes = ListSubTypes.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
DataBase.Type.Where(s => s.SubType.Select(st => st.SubTypesID).Intersect(subTypes).Any())
```

Here's an example based off of your code.

```
public static List<DropdownModel> GetTypesBySubTypes(List<string> ListSubTypes)
    {
        List<DropdownModel> Types = new List<DropdownModel>();
        List<int> subTypes = ListSubTypes.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();

        using (DocumentXtractorEntities DataBase = new DocumentXtractorEntities())
        {
                Types.AddRange((from C in DataBase.Type
                               .Where(s => s.Active 
                                       && subTypes.Intersect(s.SubType.Select(st => st.SubTypesID)).Any())
                                select new DropdownModel()
                                {
                                    ID = C.TypeID,
                                    Description = C.Name,
                                }).ToList());

        }
        return Types;
    }
```

HTH

Comment: For reasons of performance I've chosen this as the accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a similar join query to how you wrote your sql.

```
from C in DataBase.Type
join s in DataBase.SubType.Where(s => s.Active && s.SubTypeId == SubTypeIDINT) on C.TypeID equals s.TypeID
select new DropdownModel()
    {
        ID = C.TypeID,
        Description = C.Name,
    }
```